# How do I add a delay timer?

Tags: javascript, jquery, timer

I have this code that makes menu items slide down and up. I want to add a timer so there is a delay in the slide down then back up.

```
$(function () {
    $("#menu").find("li").each(function () {
        if ($(this).find("ul").length > 0) {
            $(this).mouseenter(function () {
                $(this).find("ul").stop(true, true).slideDown();
            });
            $(this).mouseleave(function () {
                $(this).find("ul").stop(true, true).slideUp();
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: What does this have to do with Java? What programming language is this?

Comment: I think you can use the following instead of `each` to add event listeners `$("#menu ul li ul:not(:empty)").mouseenter(function(){...})
    .mouseleave(function(){...});`

Answer (score 4):

It appears like you're writing javascript with jQuery

jQuery has a built in `.delay` function for animation queues.

In your example, delaying the slidedown animation by 300 ms would look like

```
$(this).find("ul").stop(true, true).delay(300).slideDown();
```

See [jQuery's delay](http://api.jquery.com/delay/)

Answer (score 0):

A smart approach would be to add a *hover intent* to **wait** before triggering mouseleave:

### *[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/obemuw/edit#javascript,html,live)*

```
$("#menu").find("li:has(ul)").on('mouseenter mouseleave',function( e ){
     var $UL = $(this).find('ul');
     if(e.type==='mouseenter'){
          clearTimeout( $(this).data('wait') );
          $UL.stop(1,1).slideDown();
     }else{            
          $(this).data('wait', setTimeout(function(){
              $UL.stop().slideUp();
          },180) );     
     } 
});
```

- instead of using `if ($(this).find("ul").length > 0) {` just use: `("li:has(ul)")`
   to trigger your events only on `li` elements that *has* `ul` as children.
- add an event callback `e` for the `mouseenter mouseleave`.
- if the `e` event == `mouseenter` ..... `else` is `mouseleave`.
- Than clear the `data` attribute called 'wait' and slideDown the children `ul`
- Now, **leaving** the original `li` element to reach the 'distant' `ul` we have to cross over a white space (demo) that will usually trigger immediately the 'slideUp()', but we set a timeout counter inside that `li`'s data attribute that will wait ~180ms before running.
- Reaching the 'distant' `ul` element - beeing a children of the timeouted 'li' we clear the timeout (step 1) 'retaining' the mouseenter state.

use ~180ms or how much you think is needed to reach with the mouse the 'distant' UL element

Comment: @user1510450 You're welcome! Hope I guessed well your needs. (Welcome to SO; make sure to read the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) and this: [How to accept an answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) )